# Adding/Subtracting a time period to current time (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, date

I'm a little confused! I have the following bit of JS

```
//Set datetimes for the centre of the Timeline and the highlighting period
var myCurrentDateTime = new Date();
var MS_PER_MINUTE = 60000;
var MinsToDeductForCentre = 1440
var MinsEitherSideOfNow = 720
var myTLcenterdate = new Date(myCurrentDateTime - (MinsToDeductForCentre * MS_PER_MINUTE));
var tldate = myTLcenterdate.toString()
var hlStartDate = new Date(myCurrentDateTime - (MinsEitherSideOfNow * MS_PER_MINUTE));
var hlEndDate = new Date(myCurrentDateTime + (MinsEitherSideOfNow * MS_PER_MINUTE));
```

myTLcentredate gives me a Date 24h prior to current time

hlStartDate gives me a Date 12h prior to current time

BUT hlEndDate gives a NotANumber error...

it basically treats myCurrentDateTime and the value of MinsEitherSideOfNow * MS_PER_MINUTE (43200000) as strings and joins them giving for example "Thu May 17 10:44:17 UTC+0100 201243200000"

Why?

Comment: you code seems fine to me.. I tried it and got no exception. just try "alert("typeof hlEndDate is "+ (typeof hlEndDate));" and you get :"typeof hlEndDate is object". So your hlEndDate  remains a "Date" object. nothing wrong about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to add or subtract minutes from a date, this would be sufficient:

```
var dSubtract = new Date, 
    dAdd = new Date;
// let dSubtract be Thu May 17 2012 12:11:54 GMT+0200
// and dAdd         Thu May 17 2012 12:11:54 GMT+0200
dSubtract.setMinutes(dSubtract.getMinutes()-1440); 
//=> dSubtract is now: Wed May 16 2012 12:00:54 GMT+0200
dAdd.setMinutes(dAdd.getMinutes()+720);
//=> dAdd is now: Fri May 18 2012 00:00:54 GMT+0200
```

(example in my timezone ofcourse)

Comment: Thanks... I have used this as it's much more understandable. I just couldn't understand why in hlStartTime the parts of the expression were treated as a mathematical equation while in hlEndTime the same expressions were treated as strings.

Comment: Glad I could help. I ran your code in Chromes developer tools, but that didn't show the problem you mentioned. It may be a browser problem?

Comment: I was using IE8... The only browser the company allow :(

Answer (score 0):

Use the function parseInt on both of the variales, like so:

```
parseInt(var1) * parseInt(var2)
```

Comment: how this even related to something?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
function SubtractTime(objStartdatetime, objEnddatetime) {
//var T1 = new Date("2012/02/14 8:10:00");

d = new Date();
     T1 = new Date(objStartdatetime);
     T2 = new Date(objEnddatetime);        
      misec = T2.getTime() - T1.getTime();
```

}

function AddTime(objStartdatetime, objEnddatetime) {
    //var T1 = new Date("2012/02/14 8:10:00");

```
d = new Date();
     T1 = new Date(objStartdatetime);
     T2 = new Date(objEnddatetime);        
      misec = T2.getTime() + T1.getTime();
```

}